# What is called if 2 bools are true in if/else statements

Tags: if-statement, boolean

In a normal if/else statement if one bool, for example, is true it calls that statement
e.g:

```
bool1 = true;
bool2 = false;
bool3 = false;

if(bool1){
    DoSomething();
}else if(bool2){
    DoSomethingElse();
}else{
    DoSomethingHelpful();
}
```

Of course, in this example `DoSomething()` will be called.

But what if 2 or 3 of the bools were equal to true, e.g:

```
bool1 = true;
bool2 = true;
bool3 = false;

if(bool1){
    DoSomething();
}else if(bool2){
    DoSomethingElse();
}else{
    DoSomethingHelpful();
}
```

What statement will be called? Would it be `DoSomething()` because its the first statement read by the compiler?Or would it just return with an error

Comment: Instructions are sequentially run, so if the first bool1 is true, only the first DoSomething() will be executed.

Comment: You can easily test this for yourself. C compilers, Java compilers and Javascript interpreters are free. And chances are you have at least one of these on your computer already ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if`, `elseif` and `else` can also be seen as:

```
if (bool1) {
  DoSomething();
} else {
    if (bool2) {
        DoSomethingElse();
    } else {
       DoSomethingHelpful();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DoSomething() will be called because of the first statement satisfies the condition, therefore the compiler will not generate an error and other conditions will be skipped.